# Does Bash Wait command support -n option?

Tags: bash, shell, wait

There is a bash script usage 'Wait -n' for wait any of processes to exit. But it got error information. The part of script is:

```
# wait for any of the coord or workers to exit
# `jobs` ensures that any completed old processes from other tests
# are not waited upon
jobs &> /dev/null
wait -n
```

The Error info

```
 wait: -n: invalid option
```

So is the -n opthion a new feature for wait command?

Comment: Which version of bash are you using?
-n is pretty old option...

Comment: It seems that the error message answers the question for the shell you are using.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I see you're doing 6.824 lab1 on a mac. For future fellow learners: just [install latest bash using homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/292760/265041) and run the script with homebrew's bash, i.e. `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` for ARM and `/usr/local/bin/bash` for Intel.

Answer (score 3):

> Does Bash Wait command support -n option?

Yes.

> So is the -n opthion a new feature for wait command?

It was introduced [8 years ago](https://github.com/bminor/bash/commit/ac50fbac377e32b98d2de396f016ea81e8ee9961) as part of bash4.3. I would count that as "old".

Comment: macOS still ships with bash v3.2.57 (for licensing reasons), so if they're using macOS...

Comment: I still have some RHEL 7 systems that have bash 4.2 whit out the wait -n ...
is there a neat workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as KamilCuk said 'wait -n' was introduced in  bash version 4.3 (bash-4.3-alpha to be precise).
Bash maintainer keeps the changelog online [here](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES), should one need to see when some generic feature was introduced.

If you have an older version you can create a function that behaves similarly, something like this:

```
wait-n ()
{ StartJobs="$(jobs -p)"
  CurJobs="$(jobs -p)"
  while diff -q  <(echo -e "$StartJobs") <(echo -e "$CurJobs") >/dev/null
  do
    sleep 1
    CurJobs="$(jobs -p)"
  done
}
```

You can make it more complicated and have it behave closer to the real 'wait -n' but I just wanted something that would wait for any one of the background jobs to terminate.The above example will also return if a new background job is started which may be unwanted.
to work around this issue one could see if the output of

```
comm  -23 <(echo -e "$StartJobs") <(echo -e "$CurJobs")
```

is non empty instead of using diff.

I did try to trap SIGCHLD but it seems to go to the parent shell not the one that is interpreting the script.